# How to create a Td with colspan attribute using wffweb?

Tags: java, wffweb

I am writing an java application to create a HTML file which will be used a report. I am using **wffweb** to create the HTML document.
I am trying to programmatically create a table as mention below:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td> Column 1 <td>
   <td> Column 2 <td>
   <td> Column 3 <td>
   <td> Column 3 <td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> Column 1 <td>
   <td colspan="3"> Column 2 <td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there any possible way to create a column which spans multiple column using **wffweb**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CustomAttribute` class for providing colspan attribute to the `td` TAG. Here is the sample code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Html html = new Html(null) {
        Body body = new Body(this) {
            Table table = new Table(this, new CustomAttribute("border",
                    "1px")) {

                {
                    Tr tr = new Tr(this) {
                        Td td1 = new Td(this) {
                            Blank cellContent = new Blank(this, "1");
                        };
                        Td td2 = new Td(this) {
                            Blank cellContent = new Blank(this,
                                    "First Name");
                        };
                        Td td3 = new Td(this) {
                            Blank cellContent = new Blank(this, "Last Name");
                        };
                    };
                    Tr tr1 = new Tr(this) {
                        Td td1 = new Td(this, new CustomAttribute(
                                "colspan", "3")) {
                            Blank cellContent = new Blank(this,
                                    "First Name");
                        };

                    };

                }

            };
        };
    };

    html.setPrependDocType(true);
    System.out.println(html.toHtmlString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In latest version it has support for `ColSpan` and `RowSpan`. You can also use their [tool to convert html to wff java code as shown in this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iM3L2X1jQww).